# Template tries to reference model before it is created

Tags: angular, angular2-template

My template is trying to reference a property of a model, like so: `{{someModel.propertyName}}`. The value of the model is passed by the outer component, so it is defined like this: `@Input() someModel: someModelInterface = new SomeModel();`. The outer component gets this model **asynchronously**, using Observable.
I am getting an error, that template can not display property `propertyName` of `undefined`.
I get this error even if I create an empty instance of the model in the constructor.
I understand why this is happening: at the time that the template is trying to render the property of the model, the model is not passed, yet. I was able to solve this by adding the `?` in the panel `{{someModel?.propertyName}}` but this does not look like a clean solution, more like a workaround. Is there a better way?
Also, why does template see it as undefined even though I create it in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{{someModel?.propertyName}}
```

This way Angular doesn't throw if `someModel` is still null when it tries to bind `propertyName`.

`?.` is the safe navigation operator (Elvis operator) which returns `null` if the part before `?.` is `null` and doesn't even try to access `propertyName` as long as `someModel` is `null`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you are saying, but it seems that there should be a better way. Also, why doesn't template "see" the model if I am creating it in the constructor and when it is defined?

Comment: You said you are fetching it asynchronuosly, or did I misinterpret something?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you already use `?.` as workaround. This is the right way to do it anyway.